# Where Should Hadoop Store Files Added

Tags: hadoop, version, storage

I've installed version 0.22.0 of Hadoop, and did the formatting of namenode. But when I add a file (using hadoop fs -put command), the file is added to the current folder of the operating system rather than to the Hadoops storage folder ( which I think is /tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name). I have worked with version 1.0.4 as well, and in the case of 1.0.4, any file thatyou added ended up in Hadoop's storage folder rather than being added to the current folder of the operating system. So, is version 0.22.0 suppose to do that?

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not configure/start a (pseudo)-cluster, so local filesystem is used by default. Check settings at hadoop-0.22.0/conf folder. See http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html for how to setup Pseudo-Cluster. Run HDFS daemons using `bin/start-dfs.sh` script.